# Question on a Proof regarding exponential matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to prove following statement

> Let $A$,$B$ $\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ such that
>   $$e^{t(R+S)}= e^{tR}e^{tS}$$
>   Prove that RS = SR

My proof is the following and I'm unsure about one step: I don't know if I'm allowed to do it or not.

*Proof*:

$$e^{tR}e^{tS}=e^{t(R+S)}=e^{t(S+R)}=e^{tS}e^{tR}$$

$$\iff tRtS = tStR \iff RS = SR$$

Am I allowed to say that $e^{tR}e^{tS}= e^{tS}e^{tR} \implies tRtS = tStR$? my question comes from the fact that I'm working with matrices and not with numbers thus I can't take the logarithms to both part.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try taking a derivative of $f(t) = e^{tR}e^{tS}$ instead.

Comment: 1st problem: the logarithm is only definied in a open ball around the identity in the space of invertible matrices, your proof only works for small $t$.

Comment: 2nd problem: in your proof you already assume that $R$ and $S$ commute!

Comment: @Blah I assume the the sum of two matrices commute $\implies R+S = S+R$. however thank you for the answer, I'll prove it in another way :D

Comment: You have to know that $(tR)(tS)=(tS)(tR)$ for your first step $$e^{tR}e^{tS}=e^{(tR)+(tS)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your proof is valid. You claim that $e^{tR}e^{tS}=e^{t(R+S)}=\color{red}{e^{t(S+R)}=e^{tS}e^{tR}}$, but the third equality sign (i.e. the equality I colored in red) is not justisfied. And I also don't see understand why the implication $e^{tR}e^{tS}= e^{tS}e^{tR} \implies tRtS = tStR$ holds.

To prove the proposition, you may differentiate the given condition on both sides **twice** w.r.t. $t$, and then put $t=0$.