# A question about exponential matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

So here is my question,

I would like to prove,

If $R,S\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ are matrices such that,
$$e^{t(R+S)}=e^{tR}e^{tS},\;\forall t\in\mathbb R$$
Then,
$$RS=SR$$

And here is what i did,

$$e^{t(R+S)}=e^{tR}e^{tS}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow0=e^{t(R+S)}-e^{tR}e^{tS}$$
This implies,

$$0=\frac{d}{dt}(e^{t(R+S)}-e^{tR}e^{tS})$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 0=(R+S)e^{t(R+S)}-Re^{tR}e^{tS}-e^{tR}Se^{tS}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 0=Re^{tR}e^{tS}+Se^{tR}e^{tS}-Re^{tR}e^{tS}-e^{tR}Se^{tS}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow 0=Se^{tR}e^{tS}-e^{tR}Se^{tS}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow Se^{tR}e^{tS}=e^{tR}Se^{tS}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow Se^{tR}=e^{tR}S$$
By differentiating on both sides we obtain,

$$SRe^{tR}=Re^{tR}S$$
Setting $t=0$ proves finally the claim,

$$SR=RS$$

Could someone look over my prove an tell me if it is correct, or if not give me a hint where I made a mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Looks familiar: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/739390/19341 Do you know Ale?

Comment: Looks fine to me.